# Creating link table to connect one to one relationship of same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I want to make sure table join with joining table has strong one-to-one relationship. Following is example
Run generator

```
bundle exec rails g model Page name:string content:text
bundle exec rails g model PageAssociation left_page_id:integer right_page_id:integer
```

After running these generator, I have to change my `page` model following

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :left_page_association, :foreign_key => :left_page_id,
           :class_name => 'PageAssociation'
  has_one :right_page_association, :foreign_key => :right_page_id,
           :class_name => 'PageAssociation'
  has_one :left_page, :through => :left_page_association,
           :source => :right_page
  has_one :right_page, :through => :right_page_association,
           :source => :left_page
end
```

In my association table model `page_association`

```
class PageAssociation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :left_page, class_name: 'Page'
  belongs_to :right_page, class_name: 'Page'
end
```

Now using `rails c` I can do following

```
page_one = Page.create(name: 'first page', content: 'first page content')
page_two = Page.create(name: 'second page', content: 'second page content')
PageAssociation.create(left_page: page_one, right_page: page_two)
page_one.left_page
page_two.right_page
```

All working fine and it is returning pages. but I can do also this

```
page_three = Page.create(name: 'third page', content: 'third page content')
PageAssociation.create(left_page: page_one, right_page: page_three)
```

Of course it still shows on relationship due to `has_one` but it is creating another relationship. So I want following

1. Only one association can be created and it should not allow another one
2. What is best way to do this as we have million of records
3. Is it one to use page.left_page? or is there any other optimised way to do same thing.
4. Should I add **indexing** using following migration lines. Does it effect performance.

```
add_foreign_key :page_associations, :pages, column: :left_page_id
add_foreign_key :page_associations, :pages, column: :right_page_id
```

I changed migration to make column value unique, so it now give error when I create another PageAssociate with same page.id but is it right way?

```
      t.integer :left_page_id, null: false, index: { unique: true }
      t.integer :right_page_id, null: false, index: { unique: true }
```

#### what problem I am solving

So I have books table where I have multiple books, but some books borrow pages from one another. So suppose I have book-A and book-B so I want to show relationship of book-a to book-b. If they are related then I will create another relationship of book-a page-10 linked to book-b page 20, so when I click on book-a to synchronise, it will bring all changes of book-b page 20 in my book-a.
So above is my first step to connected two books. I understand solving it using self join and keys is best but I can't do as we have huge number of records so that is not possible. So I have used above method to do it. But I did add unique constraints on db and validations in model to solve it. but I feel it is still not good way of doing it.
later one I will make following

```
main-book , main-book-page, secondary-book-page
```

This will allow me to bound later pages each other. The name book and pages are fictions, actually entities are different.

Comment: I don't think this is the right model for your domain - if its a strong one to one association you should maybe just add a self referential foreign key to the pages table that points to the previous/next page or use an ordinal column  to number the pages (within a book). The only way to make your join table scheme work would be to add a third foreign key to the page_associations table (belongs_to :book) and then make the index on that column.

Comment: You might want to consider presenting the domain and tell us what real world problem you're attempting to solve and focus less on your attempted solution. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20asking,trouble%2C%20you%20ask%20about%20Y.

Comment: Sure I am adding updating my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is really just a normal many to many table setup:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_pages
  has_many :pages, through: :book_pages
end

class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_pages
  has_many :books, through: :book_pages
end

class BookPage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :page
  validates_uniqueness_of :book_id, scope: :page_id
end
```

Uniqueness in this case can be guarenteed by adding a unique index:

```
add_index :book_pages, [:book_id, :page_id]
```

### Why?

M2M join table setups where you have two foreign keys that are assigned arbitrarily  are not a very good design and don't work well with ActiveRecord since you can't define assocations with an `OR` clause.

Each association can only have a single foreign key. This means that you can't treat it as a homogenius collection and cannot eager load it.

That means you need to write crappy joins like this instead of being able to work with a proper assocation:

```ruby
Book.joins(
  "LEFT JOIN pages_assocations pa ON pa.left_page_id = books.id OR pa.left_page_id = books.id"
)
```

And you also have to write steaming piles when creating indirect assocations.

While the table setup with a single row per book/page combo may seem to require more rows on the onset its also much more flexible as you can map out the assocations between books by subqueries, lateral joins or grouping and counting the number of matches.

```ruby
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_pages
  has_many :pages, through: :book_pages

  def books_with_pages_in_common
     Book.where(
        id: BookPage.select(:book_id)
                    .where(page_id: pages)
     )
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I got your point, but I have this design suggested by seniors so can't change it. only way out was to put few validations and use same many_many relationship. For me most of things are working fine. Thank you.